# How to go to a Wildcard link (site) based on the users login details on Sharepoint Wss3.0

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, hyperlink, wss

I am currently using Sharepoint Wss 3.0, I know that Wss do not offer "Mysite" like Sharepoint 2007. We have about +/- 200 users with our company, which i want a "Mysite" or a personal site for each user.

I managed to create currently 10 users with a sub site like below eg:
http://itds008:13864/sites/Intranet/mysite/shabeersa

in the link above "shabeersa" is the user on our AD system and which the user login into sharepoint.

NOW. I WANT TO KNOW " How to go to a Wildcard link (site) based on the users login details on Sharepoint Wss3.0"

All i want to provide the users is eg link: http://itds008:13864/sites/Intranet/mysite/*$**(user)$$$

Please help

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create a page in the layouts folder that redirects the user to his personal site. The reason why the page should be in the layouts folder, is because that supports server side code without the need for adding a page parser path in your web.config.

If you want a more 'user friendly' url, you could also create a web part that handles the redirection and put that web part on http://itds008:13864/sites/intranet/mysite for example.

[Offtopic]
By the way... I put 'user friendly' in quotes because your url is not exactly easy to remember for your end-users. I would consider using a host header for setting up web applications in SharePoint.